# Comparing values of a dataframe for greater than a given value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with values in one column. If these values are over 6.4 I need to compute the value of another column. How can I do this? This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
  if df['MAG'] >= 6.4:
    df['timeWindow'] = 10 ** 0.032 * df['MAG'] + 2.7389
else:
    df['timeWindow'] = 10 ** 0.5409 * df['MAG'] - 0.547
```

I receive this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), 
a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout `np.where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is failing because `df['MAG'] >= 6.4` returns a `pd.Series` of the same size as `df['MAG']` with multiple booleans instead of simply one. Hence the ambiguity, hence the error. You need to check `'MAG'` and create new values for `timeWindow` both at the same time. See the following:

Starting a new DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([5.3, 4.2, 7.8, 9.2], columns=["MAG"])
```

1. You can use `pd.Series.apply()` which does not require any external library:

```py
df["timeWindow"] = df.MAG.apply(
    lambda x: x * (10 ** 0.032) + 2.7389 if x >= 6.4 
              else x * (10 ** 0.5409) - 0.547
)

print(df)
#    MAG  timeWindow
# 0  5.3   17.868176
# 1  4.2   14.046158
# 2  7.8   11.135329
# 3  9.2   12.642380
```

2. Or, as suggested by @Quang Hoang, you may also use `np.where()`:

```py
import numpy as np
df["timeWindow"] = np.where(
    df.MAG >= 6.4, 
    df.MAG * (10 ** 0.032) + 2.7389, 
    df.MAG * (10 ** 0.5409) - 0.547
)

print(df)
#    MAG  timeWindow
# 0  5.3   17.868176
# 1  4.2   14.046158
# 2  7.8   11.135329
# 3  9.2   12.642380
```

Answer (score 0):

'Where' is also available in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

cond = df['MAG'] >= 6.4

if_true = 10 ** 0.032 * df['MAG'] + 2.7389
if_false = 10 ** 0.5409 * df['MAG'] - 0.547

df['timeWindow'] = (if_true).where(cond, if_false)
```

The difference is:

**Numpy:**

```
np.where(condition, what if true, what if false)
```

**Pandas:**

```
(what if true).where(condition, what if false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set values on dataframe slices using [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```py
df.loc[df["MAG"] >= 6.4, "timeWindow"] = 10 ** 0.032 * df['MAG'] + 2.7389
df.loc[df["MAG"] < 6.4, "timeWindow"] = 10 ** 0.5409 * df['MAG'] - 0.547
```